# Django: How to serialize QuerySet into object instead of array?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to serialize a `QuerySet` into a JSON object instead of JSON array.

For model `Day`, the serialized `QuerySet` should be an object with `Day.date` keys and serialized `Day`s as values.

```
class DaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Day
        exclude = []
```

This returns an array of serialized objects:

```
DaySerializer(Day.objects.all(),many=True).data

{'15.02.2005':{...},
 '16.02.2005':{...},
  ...
}
```

I'm curious if there is some DRF way to do that.

Comment: from where these dates are coming?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is not an out-of-the-box way of doing that, but you can override `.to_representation()` and `.to_internal_value()` methods of the serializer to achieve that.

These methods enable you to alter how both serialization and de-serialization is done.

See [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) for details.

Comment: I dont think this would help. Because **`to_representation()`** is only handling one object at a time.

Comment: Did you try it? I suspect incoming `instance` would be a list of objects if `many=True`.

Comment: Yes.. The many=True magic is being carried out somewhere else.